# Wordpress - Get an image using the media library

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, image, forms

#### I'm creating a plugin and i have an admin page

In the options of that page, i would like to add a button that allow me to open the Wordpress media library and select an image from it, after that, get the URL of the selected image and the `alt` attribute.

#### If it is possible, how can i do that using AJAX?

Answer (score 10):

First you would need to enqueue wordpress core media scripts and a custom js script

```
function my_enqueue_media_lib_uploader() {

    //Core media script
    wp_enqueue_media();

    // Your custom js file
    wp_register_script( 'media-lib-uploader-js', plugins_url( 'media-lib-uploader.js' , __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'media-lib-uploader-js' );
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_media_lib_uploader');
```

Then let say you have this markup within your options page: an upload button and a text input to store the selected image url

```
<form method="post">
    <input id="image-url" type="text" name="image" />
    <input id="upload-button" type="button" class="button" value="Upload Image" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

You need to add this javascript code to invoke the uploader popup

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  var mediaUploader;

  $('#upload-button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // If the uploader object has already been created, reopen the dialog
      if (mediaUploader) {
      mediaUploader.open();
      return;
    }
    // Extend the wp.media object
    mediaUploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
      title: 'Choose Image',
      button: {
      text: 'Choose Image'
    }, multiple: false });

    // When a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
    mediaUploader.on('select', function() {
      attachment = mediaUploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
      $('#image-url').val(attachment.url);
    });
    // Open the uploader dialog
    mediaUploader.open();
  });

});
```

Once the image is selected, your **image-url** input will now contain the url and will be saved on form submit.

Answer (score 0):

The use case is: I have plugin that contain index.php as main file, I want to be able to click on a button and the media library opened and select an image from it, this image should be load into an image tag.

## 1- add script to your main PHP plugin

```php
// index.php

// ...

// add script js for page
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', function () {
    // Enqueue WordPress media scripts
    if ($_GET["page"]== 'debug_area') {
        wp_enqueue_media();
        // Enqueue custom script that will interact with wp.media
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'myprefix_script',
            plugins_url('/load_img.js', __FILE__),
            array('jquery'),
            '0.1');
    }
});

// add ajax action to get the image async
add_action('wp_ajax_get_image_from_media_lib', function () {
    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image(
            filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT),
            'medium',
            false,
            array('id' => 'image_preview')
        );
        $data = array(
            'image' => $image,
        );
        wp_send_json_success($data);
    } else {
        wp_send_json_error();
    }
});
```

## 2- add file JS that already included in enqueue

```js
// load_img.js
jQuery(document).ready(_ => {
    console.clear();

    /**
     * Define media_lib_frame as wp.media object
     */
    const media_lib_frame = wp.media({
        title: 'Select Media',
        multiple: false,
        library: {
            type: 'image',
        }
    });

    /**
     * On close, get selections and save to the hidden input
     * plus other AJAX stuff to refresh the image preview
     */
    media_lib_frame.on('close', _ => {
        const selection = media_lib_frame.state().get('selection');
        const gallery_ids = selection.map(attachment => attachment['id']);
        const ids = gallery_ids.join(",");
        jQuery('input#idImage').val(ids);
        loadImage(ids);
    });

    /**
     * On open, get the id from the hidden input
     * and select the appropriate images in the media manager
     */
    media_lib_frame.on('open', _ => {
        const selection = media_lib_frame.state().get('selection');
        const ids = jQuery('input#idImage').val().split(',');
        ids.forEach(id => {
            const attachment = wp.media.attachment(id);
            attachment.fetch();
            selection.add(attachment ? [attachment] : []);
        });
    });

    jQuery('button#btnOpenMediaLibFrame').click(e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        media_lib_frame.open();
    });
});

// Ajax request to refresh the image preview
const loadImage = the_id => {
    const data = {action: 'get_image_from_media_lib', id: the_id};

    jQuery.get(ajaxurl, data, response => {
        if (response.success === true) {
            jQuery('#image_preview').replaceWith(response.data.image);
        }
    });
}
```

## 3- add this HTML into the function that responsible for render view

```html
<img id="image_preview"/>
<input
    type="hidden"
    id="idImage"
    class="regular-text"/>
<button
    type='button'
    class="button-primary"
    id="btnOpenMediaLibFrame">
    Select a image
</button>
```