# How Can I pass an image file to wp_handle_upload?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been looking everywhere for this and not able to find an answer.

I need to pass a file from the url source to wp_handle_upload. How can I accomplish this?

Thank you, hopefully i`ll get the answer

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :-) What have you tried so far?
Please look at [ask]
and [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32892412/wordpress-get-an-image-using-the-media-library)

```
function my_enqueue_media_lib_uploader() {

    //Core media script
    wp_enqueue_media();

    // Your custom js file
    wp_register_script( 'media-lib-uploader-js', plugins_url( 'media-lib-uploader.js' , __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'media-lib-uploader-js' );
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_media_lib_uploader');


jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  var mediaUploader;

  $('#upload-button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // If the uploader object has already been created, reopen the dialog
      if (mediaUploader) {
      mediaUploader.open();
      return;
    }
    // Extend the wp.media object
    mediaUploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
      title: 'Choose Image',
      button: {
      text: 'Choose Image'
    }, multiple: false });

    // When a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
    mediaUploader.on('select', function() {
      attachment = mediaUploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
      $('#image-url').val(attachment.url);
    });
    // Open the uploader dialog
    mediaUploader.open();
  });

});

<form method="post">
    <input id="image-url" type="text" name="image" />
    <input id="upload-button" type="button" class="button" value="Upload Image" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```